# How can I alias 'emacs file.txt' to 'emacs file.txt &'?

Tags: alias, tcsh

In case this is an XY problem, what I'd like to do is always open Emacs visually as a background process, but still get tab completion and not have to append '&' manually. I'm in Tcsh, no way to change that. I don't know how or if it's possible to alias something to pass an input and append something to it - is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in tcsh this is possible (unlike Bourne-style shells where you'd need to use a function instead). You need to put `!*` in the alias text to substitute the parameters passed to the alias, and more stuff can go after that.

```
alias emacs 'emacs \!* &'
```

It's more useful to use its integrated server. Starting from Emacs 22 (IIRC), you can easily run `emacsclient` and make it start Emacs if it isn't started yet. (With earlier versions, `emacsclient` exists but is less useful.)

```
alias e 'emacsclient -a "" \!* &'
```

And if Emacs is running and you just want to open a new window, then there's no need to run emacsclient in the background: tell it to open the file in the existing Emacs instance and exit.

```
alias e 'emacsclient -a "" -c \!*'
```

Comment: Sorry if offtopic, but you can do that in bash or ksh93 too with `alias e='_e=$(fc -nl -0); emacs ${_e#*e} & #'`. There is a similar trick for zsh. Using an alias has the advantage that you can access the unexpanded command line eg. `alias c='_c=$(fc -nl -0); bc -l <<<${_c#*c} #'` then `c 7.15 * (3.33 / 4)`.

Comment: @mosvy That doesn't really work though. The alias has to be the sole command on the command line and the arguments can't include special characters. E.g. `e "file with spaces.txt"` or `cd directory; e file.txt` or `e file.txt; ls`

Comment: That could be fixed with a little imagination: `alias e='_e=$(fc -nl -0); _e=" ${_e##*;}"; eval "${_e/ e /emacs } &" #'`. This still won't work with `e foo && e bar` or `e foo; echo done`, but this wasn't intended as a demo of how to make aliases work exactly as functions. Again, sorry for bringing off-topic stuff in a csh-related answer.